# .Net List to a SOAP Array and back to a .Net List

Tags: vb.net, soap

Within a Web Service CarService,

- I have a class called Car.
- Car has a bunch of properties i.e. Car.Color.
- CarService has a method called GetCars().
- Within GetCar, I have a loop that appends a List of, you guessed it.. Cars.

  Dim carList As New List(Of Car)

  Do While rdr.Read()
      If rdr.GetValue(1).ToString().Length > 0 Then
          Dim c As Car = New Car
          c.Color = rdr.GetValue(1).ToString()
          carList.Add(c)
      End If
  Loop

GetCars() returns carList. 

I also have another page within a different project that consumes that data.

Or at least, I'd like to and here's my problem..

If I do..

```
Dim myNewCars As List(Of Namespace.Car)
myNewCars = CarServiceProxy.GetCars()
```

I get:

Value of type '1-dimensional array of Namespace.Car' cannot be converted to 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of Namespace.Car)'.

What would be the best way to convert this 1-dimensional array' back into a List of Cars?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without changing anything? Use the `List<T>` constructor that accepts `IEnumerable<T>` - so in C# (my VB isn't great):

```
List<Car> myNewCars = new List<Car>(CarServiceProxy.GetCars());
```

If you can change things; perhaps consider things like the WCF usage where you can specify the collection type (of all methods) - the `scvutil /collectionType:` switch. Changing to a WCF stack is non-trivial, though.

Comment: When using the /collectionType parameter mind the funky generic-notation with the blackquote mark. Eg. if you want to force svcutil to use List<T> collections then you have to specify this: /ct:System.Collections.Generic.List`1

Answer (score 1):

With .NET 3.5 (and .NET 4.0) you could do:

```
Dim myNewCars As List(Of Namespace.Car)
myNewCars = CarServiceProxy.GetCars().ToList()
```